# Monotouch.Dialog: Is there a simple way to make the Search Bar stay at the top of a UITableView when scrolling?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm using Monotouch.Dialog and the search bar seems to be integrated into the tableview/root element.  Therefore it scrolls with the table view, so you must be at the top of the tableview to see the search bar.

I'd like to keep using the monotouch.dialog, but I would really like it to be an element above the tableView that stays at the top when the user scrolls.  Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the search bar too much so I don't know it's search parameters, however, putting it in the parent navigationController would keep it at the top of your screen (you can code the location) and the search bar is independent of your table view.  I'm sure you can define the scope of the search bar separately.

```
navigationController.View.AddSubview (<searchbar>);
```

Be sure to handle dismissing it when you navigate (doesn't automatically get popped out of the stack)